# Java -- JDialog unmovable

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

What code will facilitate making a `JDialog` unmovable? I've looked at two options:

1. `setUndecorated(true);` which works but removes all the trimmings.
2. `addComponentListener` and overriding the `componentMoved()` method, which causes the `JDialog` to subsequently call `induceEpilepticSeizure()`  upon moving.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It might give an idea for an approach that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first instinct is - you can't unless you DO use setUndecorated(true)... You could manually put some trimmings there, but, well, UGH!

So if you want the native trimmings AND you want it immovable without the horrible flickering from using a component listener, I think you can't.

You could create a border manually that LOOKS like the default border...here's an example of how to do it, although I've intentionally made the border look like the ugliest thing you've seen all day. You'll need to find the right combination of BorderFactory calls to achieve what  you want to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JDialog frame = new JDialog((Frame) null, "MC Immovable");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.GREEN, Color.RED));
    panel.add(new JLabel("You can't move this"));

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: My reason for not using setUndecorated(true) is that I want to keep the default border. Is a Window borderless? Thanks guy.